# Do I need to create another new app for Today Extension even it's included in its parent app at iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, today-extension

My current app bundle identifier on App Store is **xxx.xxx.Classic**

My today extension bundle identifier which is declare inside xxx.xxx.Classic project is **xxx.xxx.Classic.TodayExtension**

So,different identifier means should I need to create another app at iTunes Connect for that today extension?

For now I just finished creating provision profile for development and distribution of my today extension using current App ID and just uploaded the archive of my current app to Testflight(iTunes Connect).

Will it include the latest today extension in that app?If not,should I need to add another app at iTunesConnect with that bundle identifier **xxx.xxx.Classic.TodayExtension**

and make archive which was today extension and upload to testflight?

Any Help?I am new to today extension.I didn't see that other apps on App Store which include today extension support with two App(Amazon and Amazon Today Extension).It just included in main app.Any help for how should i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just proceed with your current app for iTunes. There is no need of any new iTune account for TodayExtension & make sure version and build should be same of your app and TodayExtension, else it will not able to upload.

Source: Recently i have also uploaded [app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/homavo-tools-for-ebay-sellers/id1068090751?mt=8) with TodayExtension as an update.

Comment: Should be accepted answer. I have an app on the store with 20 extensions, all of them come with the app without having to do anything more than uploading the app on iTunes connect.